# Отладка ASP.NET на Defaul Web site

Tags: asp.net, отладка

В Defaul Web site указал путь к какой-то папке с сайтом. После этого VS сказала, что не может запустить отладку.

Можно ли её как-нибудь запустить? Или обязательно нужно, чтобы проект был как приложение в Defaul Web site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается нельзя.